# How add value to custom field in ActiveCampaign?

Tags: php, laravel

Here is documentation how add custom field to ActiveCampaign https://www.activecampaign.com/api/example.php?call=contact_add

Here is my code in Laravel:

```
$client = new Client();
$res = $client->request('POST', 'https://domain-example.com/admin/api.php?api_action=contact_add', [
        'form_params' => [
            'api_key' => 'api_key',
            'actid' => 'actid',
            'api_action' => 'contact_add',
            'api_output' => 'json',
            'email' => $_POST['email'],
            'field[utm_source, 0]' => $_POST['utm_source'],
            'p[123]' => 10,
            'field[%REFERRAL_PAGE%, 0]' => $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
        ]
  ]);
```

Result: contact added,but the field `utm_source` is empty. In Laravel I checked , this property is not empty before send. Other fields are not empty too, the problem is only with custom field `utm_source`. Any thoughts why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

I think is the next entry in the API what you really should use

```
field[%utm_source%,0] => $_POST['utm_source']
```